# Clojure: (double 0) vs (cast (class 0.0) 0)

Tags: clojure, casting

I'm trying to dynamically cast values of a list - I don't need to, but I'm curious what the issue is here:

```
(double 0)           ; => 0.0

(class 0.0)          ; => java.lang.Double

(cast (class 0.0) 0) ; =>  ClassCastException Cannot cast java.lang.Long to 
                     ;     java.lang.Double java.lang.Class.cast
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the captial D in `Double`. Why can't I `cast` the way I've tried in the code above?

Answer (score 5):

That's just not what `cast` does in Clojure - it is not a Java cast, because such casts make no sense in a language with dynamic rather than static types. Indeed there is really almost never a reason to call `cast` at all; I certainly haven't, in five years of Clojure programming. See the [documentation for cast](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cast): it always returns exactly its input, never anything else. Its only effect is to throw an exception if the input doesn't match the class you wanted to cast to.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `cast` didn't cast things. :)  Do you know how I would accomplish the intent of my code, even if it is kind of weird to do in Clojure?

Comment: Also, the error message sure makes it sound like `cast` is trying to cast.

Comment: @BobJarvis Huh? That case expression makes little sense at all. `(case (class "hello world") 0.0)` *also* returns 0.0, because you are just evaluating `(class x)` for side effects, throwing it away, and then unconditionally returning 0.0.

Comment: @helloChris How could I know that? I don't know the intent of your code at all. I know you are trying to cast a long to a double, which is not a thing you can do. How can I suggest an alternate approach if I don't know *why* you're doing something wrong?

Comment: @amalloy: whoops. That was supposed to be `cast`, not `case`. I'll repost the corrected comment.

Comment: Agreed that the message is less-than-clear, but it's trying to tell you that 0 is not a Double. If you execute `(cast (class 0.0) 0.0)` you get a return value of 0.0, meaning that yes, Virginia, 0.0 is a double. :-)

Answer (score 3):

On the JVM, we have the primitive `long` and `double` types and the object [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) and [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) types. You're dealing with the objects (capial L, capital D), not the primitives. The hierarchy for the objects is as follows:

```
|- Object
 |- Number
  |- Long
  |- Double
```

As you can see, though they're both a `Number`, a `Long` isn't a `Double`, so casting will fail.

To coerce to a `Double`, use that `double` function:

```
(class 0) ; => java.lang.Long

(class (double 0)) ; => java.lang.Double
```